# I got a security threat message in (VM ESXi) Management Interface

Tags: vmware-esxi

I Have a server in (Leaseweb Germany Datacenter), `VMware ESxi 6.7.0 Update 3` installed on it

the 'root' user have a very strong password similar to this level of complexity `cK62AzW@$FMu`

Today the server went down and when I tried to access the VMware ESXi management interface via the IP address I got the following threat message rather than (VMware ESXi management interface)

[image: the threat message]

I rebooted the server, then the (threat message) was gone and when I accessed to the server I got all VMs mapped to incorrect (*.vmdk) files!!! I changed the server password and fixed the issue by reattaching the correct (vmdk) files to the VMs

**How someone can make the IP address replay with this message?** I don't have any web server installed just VMware ESXi installed via Leaseweb Customer Portal

**How do they change the VMs Hard Disks file's path?**

**And How to avoid such things like that to happen again. ?**

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Details about this issue:
https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/massive-esxiargs-ransomware-attack-targets-VMware-esxi-servers-worldwide/

VMware workaround:
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/76372